# Magento 2 Installtion Assertion Failed -

Tags: magento2

[52693](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpHsP.png)

Receiving this error on our new Magento 2 Install. The issue prevents signed-in customers to use GO TO CHECKOUT BUTTON. Occurs only on Chrome, Edge, and Safari. Dev site never had the issue only occurred once in production. Anyone comes across the error before? Only when signed in, guest checkouts run smoothly. Once signed in, the customer can no longer add items to the cart. Go to checkout button never works.

Error is:
Assertion failed: titles extraction error

_

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

We had an error happening on our Cart page just today with the same “titles extraction error” string. Eventually we tracked it down to this file in the Chromium source code, [`chrome/renderer/resources/cart/cart-product-extraction.js`](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/0d367c87f3c9898d5364cc6be4062295c1043460/chrome/renderer/resources/cart/cart-product-extraction.js#L403).

…which appears to be part of Chrome’s recent New Tab Page’s “Your carts” feature, which made it to the Chrome stable channel recently:

- [Google Support / Get started with Your carts in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/11032183?hl=en)
- [Google Chrome New Tab page will show shopping carts you’ve left behind](https://9to5google.com/2021/05/18/google-chrome-new-tab-page-will-show-shopping-carts-youve-left-behind/)
- [“Chrome Cart” could soon let you shop and check out right from your browser’s new tab page](https://chromeunboxed.com/chrome-cart-feature)

There seems to be no way to opt out as a developer… but if you’re having the installation problem in other browsers too, it might be unrelated to that message?